# MagicalRecord Insert is too slow

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsmanagedobject, magicalrecord

I use MagicalRecord and have to insert several (lets say about 50) records in my database at once. This takes about 3 seconds. Is the a normal time for these inserts? Can I make that faster? I am also wondering why I get one saving statement in background and on in main thread...

Saving each element I get this LOG:

```
2012-07-10 21:27:55.319 MyApp[9815:1b53] -[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalSaves) MR_saveWithErrorCallback:](0x47f2e0) -> Saving <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x47f2e0>: ***   BACKGROUND SAVE *** Context 
2012-07-10 21:28:13.024 MyApp[9815:707] -[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalSaves) MR_saveWithErrorCallback:](0x480310) -> Saving <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x480310>: *** DEFAULT *** Context *** MAIN THREAD ***
```

The context is the default one:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext];
```

the insert code looks like this:

```
theWord = [Word MR_createEntity];
theWord.text = aCard.word;
theWord.playCount = [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];
theWord.user = user;    
[context MR_save];
```

Comment: are you saving on every insert?  You should only save after all Word objects are created.  That will help.

Comment: sometimes one is missing the obvious... thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, never call

```
[context MR_save]
```

in a loop -.-

Comment: It is not recognizable anymore... :)